# How to concurrently insert SparkSQL query output to HIVE while using it for another SparkSQL query

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to insert a SparkSQL dataframe o/p to Hive table and in parallel use same dataframe as subquery for another SaprkSQL action. Below pseudo-code should given an idea of what I am trying to achieve -

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test_app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
query1 = "select col1, col2, sum(col3) from input_table_1 group by col1, col2"
query2 = "select col1, sum(col1) from temp_table col1"
qry1_df = hive_context.sql(query1)
qry1_df.write.format("parquet").insertInto("output_table_1", overwrite=True)
qry1_df.registerTempTable("temp_table")
qry2_df = hive_context.sql(query2)
qry2_df.write.format("parquet").insertInto("output_table_2", overwrite=True)
```

I want execution of `query2` to leverage `qry1_df` output without having to recalculate entire DAG (that's what happens with above code).

UPDATE :
Based on suggestion to use cache, below is modified code

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test_app")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

hive_context = HiveContext(sc)
query1 = "select col1, col2, sum(col3) from input_table_1 group by col1, col2"
query2 = "select col1, sum(col1) from temp_table col1"
hive_context.sql("CACHE TABLE temp_table as " + query1)
qry1_df = hive_context.sql("Select * from temp_table")
qry1_df.write.format("parquet").insertInto("output_table_1", overwrite=True)    
qry2_df = hive_context.sql(query2)
qry2_df.write.format("parquet").insertInto("output_table_2", overwrite=True)
```

It works. Just one clarification - these 2 tasks, writing to Hive table "output_table_1" and execution of "query2", would happen asynchronously or sequentially?

Comment: registertemptable deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try .cacheTable() on the tempview

```
spark.cacheTable("my_table")
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using hive_context.sql("CACHE TABLE temp_table as " + query1) to avoid re-computation of DAG. But this makes qry_df1 dataframe as blank and nothing get written to hive table "output_table_1". Ask is to write o/p of qry_df1 to hive table while simultaneously using same for another query without having it to read it from HIVE or re-computing DAG.

Comment: My understanding is that this avoids recomputation

Comment: Thanks. I guess I got what I was looking for.